# Definir variável com maior número existente em arquivo

Tags: cmd

Tenho um arquivo nomeado como "lista.txt" com o conteúdo abaixo:

```
1
10
1000
333
46
4611116
498
```

Preciso criar outro arquivo, chamado "lista2.txt" ordenado do maior para o menor usando um arquivo em lotes. Tentei algumas coisas como usar o comando [sort](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html), mas não tem a saída correta.

```
sort /r lista.txt /o lista2.txt
```

Mas o resultado é incorreto

```
498
4611116
46
333
1000
10
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O sort não está funcionando pois ele está comparando alfabeticamente e não numericamente. Um jeito de corrigir isso é adicionar dígitos "0" ou " "(espaço) no começo de todos os números para todos terem o mesmo número de caracteres. Dessa forma a ordenação do sort irá funcionar.

Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32306526), uma forma de fazer isso com um arquivo em lotes é a seguinte:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Adiciona 12 espaços na frente de cada linha do arquivo:
(for /f %%i in (lista.txt) do (
    REM 12 espaços:
    set "Z=            %%i"
    REM Com esse resultado, pegue os últimos 12 caracteres, e salve num arquivo temporário:
    echo !Z:~-12!
))>temp.txt 

REM usando o sort:'
sort /r temp.txt /o temp.txt

REM removendo os espaços iniciais que foram postos inicialmente:
(for /f %%i in (temp.txt) do echo/%%i)>lista2.txt
REM deletando o arquivo temporário.
del temp.txt
```

Claro, é preciso ter certeza que não existe nenhum arquivo temp.txt na mesma pasta, pois será perdido, e que nenhum número terá mais do que 12 dígitos. Se for o caso, você pode adicionar mais espaços ao algoritmo.
Existem outras formas mais elegantes de se resolver esse problema, porém assim mantém-se o mais próximo possível da abordagem tomada.

Comment: exatamente isso, muito obrigado ;)

Answer (score 1):

Uma sugestão usando os comandos **`set`** junto com  **`find`** num loop **`for`** ordenando do maior para o menor.

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

cd /d "%~dp0" & (for /f %%i in (lista.txt)do set "_list=!_list!,%%i,") && set "_list=!_list:,,=,!"
for %%i in (!_list!-99999999)do for %%I in (!_list!)do if %%i lss %%I echo/!_x!|find ",%%I,">nul||set "_x=!_x!,%%I,"
cd.>lista2.txt & for %%i in (!_x!)do echo/%%i>>lista2.txt

for /f %%M in (lista2.txt) do echo=Maior Valor: %%M & goto :^)

:^)
type .\lista2.txt & timeout -1
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Código comentado:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

:: entra na pasta do bat ::
cd /d "%~dp0" 

:: looping for criando array _list dos itens/linhas do arquivo :: 
for /f %%i in (lista.txt)do set "_list=!_list!,%%i," 

:: remove duplicidade de virgulas no array :: 
set "_list=!_list:,,=,!"

:: usa o array em 2 loopings for para verificar %%i e %%I qual é maior para salvar no  array _x :: 
for %%i in (!_list!-99999999)do for %%I in (!_list!)do if %%i lss %%I echo/!_x!|find ",%%I,">nul||set "_x=!_x!,%%I,"

:: cria arquivo lista2.txt com os itens armazenados no array _x :: 
cd.>lista2.txt & for %%i in (!_x!)do echo/%%i>>lista2.txt

:: lista o primeira linha (maior valor salvo no lista2.txt) e exibe saido para lable :^) :: 
for /f %%M in (lista2.txt) do echo=Maior Valor: %%M & goto :^)


:^)
:: lista as linhas do maior valor para o menor salvo no lista2.txt e chama um pause :: 
type .\lista2.txt & timeout -1
```

---

Uma opção para um looping limitando a execução baseado no números de linhas no arquivo lista.txt:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d "%~dp0" 

for /f delims^=:^ tokens^=^2 %%i in ('find /c /v ";" lista.txt')do set _cnt=%%i
2>nul (cd.>"%temp%\_lista_.tmp" & cd.>"lista2.txt") & for /f %%i in (lista.txt)do echo/,%%i,>>"%tmp%\_lista_.tmp"
for /l %%L in (1 1 99999)do find ",%%L," "%temp%\_lista_.tmp" >nul && (echo/%%L>>"lista2.txt" & call set /a "_cnt-=1" && if "!_cnt!" =="0" goto :~0)

:~0  
timeout -1 & del "%temp%\_lista_.tmp" & type "lista2.txt"
```

---

Comentando ***opção para um looping limitando a execução baseado no números de linhas no arquivo***

---

```bat
:: conta as linhas/numeros estao no arquivo para usar como delimitador de execução no for /l ::
for /f delims^=:^ tokens^=^2 %%i in ('find /c /v ";" lista.txt')do set _cnt=%%i

:: cria os 2 arquivos vazios e se para caso de existirem, apaga o conteudo ::
2>nul (cd.>"%temp%\_lista_.tmp" & cd.>"lista2.txt")

:: cria string unica para cada numero/linha do arquivo "%tmp%\_lista_.tmp" ::
for /f %%i in (lista.txt)do echo/,%%i,>>"%tmp%\_lista_.tmp"

:: executa um loop numerico de 1 em 1 ate 99999, e tambem localiza ",numero," no arquivo "%tmp%\_lista_.tmp" ::
:: remove as ",," (virgulas) da string, salva (se existente), somente o numero da varivel %%L em "lista2.txt" ::
for /l %%L in (1 1 99999)do find ",%%L," "%temp%\_lista_.tmp" >nul && echo/%%L>>"lista2.txt"

:: para cada ocorencia, vai substraindo 1 do contador _cnt, para quando chegar em zero parar de listar/buscar ::
&& (echo/%%L>>"lista2.txt" & call set /a "_cnt-=1" && if "!_cnt!" =="0" goto :~0)
```

---